# Use JQuery interfaces directly typescript?

Tags: jquery, typescript

I'm new to typescript so probably I'm missing something here, In my code I'm trying to specify that a function returns an object that implements JQueryXHR interface which is in jquery library definition file (jquery.d.ts)

That's my code

```
import $ = require("jquery");

interface IProduct { ... }

class Product {
    create(product: IProduct) : JQueryXHR {
        return $.ajax(... );
    }
}
```

JQueryXHR interface is in jquery.d.ts file but I can't figure out how to reference it since it's not exported ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to the top of your file.

```
///<reference path="[RELATIVE PATH TO]/jquery.d.ts" />
```

Comment: thanks it works. I thought require is enough to include the library definitions!